# I can't register for devise in rails

Tags: devise, actioncable, ruby-on-rails-5

I can't register, only login, In the server i see this:

An unauthorized connection attempt was rejected Failed to upgrade to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: keep-alive, Upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket)

```
class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
```

identified_by :current_user

```
def connect
  self.current_user = find_verified_user
  logger.add_tags 'ActionCable', current_user.name
end

protected
  def find_verified_user
    if verified_user = User.find_by(id: cookies.signed['user.id'])
      verified_user
    else
      reject_unauthorized_connection
    end
  end
```

end

my routes

```
devise_for :users, controllers: {
    registrations: 'users/registrations',
    :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks"
 }
```

mount ActionCable.server => '/cable'

Answer (score 0):

Your connection.rb file probably has a line `identified_by :current_user`, and your `def connect` calls some variation of a custom `find_verified_user` method, which requires valid authentication as customized by your app within the same file. Your connection to ActionCable has thus been rejected when you are trying to create a user, which naturally means you were not making the request with whatever is required for valid authentication and user identification. So I guess the real question is: is there a reason you are trying to register a user through WebSocket?

Comment: I only need enter to mi app, I only need register to my users for devise, my app have more things that a chat. but I used this method thinking that it was the conventional method of entry, but I do not want it to block my registry

Comment: You don't have to use web socket to register your user. Did you follow the devise set up instructions? If yes you would have a line in your `routes.rb` that says devise for users. Generate devise views and register through non web socket template

Comment: https://gorails.com/episodes/user-authentication-with-devise you may find this helpful

Comment: I first created devise, after several more features and then put in action cable, following a tutorial, but from there I can not register in devise

Comment: i used                                                                                                                   def connect
      self.current_user = User.new || User.find(id: cookies.signed['user.id'])
      logger.add_tags 'ActionCable', current_user.name
    end                                                                                                          but it don't work

Comment: So try to register through a non websocket route that's set up by devise, since it's probably easier than configuring for web socket connection to accept non authenticated connections, plus your user registration doesn't really need to be broadcasted  anywhere

Comment: How I can connect with websocket ans I have devise too

Answer (score 0):

I'm obviously late providing this answer but I'll share what worked for me. The connection.rb referencing `cookies.signed[...]` worked when I was connecting with ActionCable directly but would be rejected when trying to use the `turbo_stream_from` element. Here's the connection.rb that works for both, when using Devise:

```
module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    identified_by :current_user

    def connect
      self.current_user = find_verified_user
    end

    protected

      def find_verified_user
        env["warden"].user || reject_unauthorized_connection
      end
  end
end
```